# Laravel 6.12 "A facade root has not been set." when using Log::

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-6

Using `Log` in unit tests causes weird error

Versions:
Laravel Framework 6.12.0
php 7.4
phpunit 8.5.2

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        Log::info('hellowli');
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

I run:

`$ php7.4 vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/ExampleTest.php`

```
$ php7.4 vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/ExampleTest.php 
PHPUnit 8.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 49 ms, Memory: 6.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Unit\ExampleTest::testBasicTest
RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.

/home/toskan/IdeaProjects/apartments/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:258
/home/toskan/IdeaProjects/apartments/laravel/tests/Unit/ExampleTest.php:17

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test case is extending the wrong base TestCase.

Simply change the namespace to:

```php
use Tests\TestCase;
```

Instead of:

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

Comment: how comes I missed that? this was the "exampletest.php" that comes from laravel, built in, and thats how it was. E.g. the `ExampleTest.php` has the wrong import from the beginning, straight from laravel installation